# Some Androids Uploading Scrambled Images

Tags: android, post, photos

First I use this code to save the photo to the Android's SD Card:

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;

    currentFilename = String.format("%d", System.currentTimeMillis());              
    outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + currentFilename + ".jpg");                    
    outStream.write(data);
    outStream.close();

    }
};
```

Then I am using this code to upload photos on Android devices:

```
public void uploadPhoto() {

        try {

            // Create HttpPost
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/upload.php");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );

            // Add the Picture as "userfile"
            entity.addPart( "userfile", new FileBody( 
                new File( "/sdcard/", currentFilename + ".jpg" ),
                "image/jpeg")
            );


            // Send the data to the server
            post.setEntity( entity );
            client.execute( post );


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // catch
        } finally {
            // finally
        }

}
```

This works on my LG Optimus V running Android 2.2.2 and Droid X running Android 2.3.4

However - a user who has an HTC Evo running 2.3.4 (Same as my Droid X) is experiencing that all of her uploaded photos are scrambled when they are saved to her phone (and when they get to the server). The image looks like an array of jagged colored lines.

Any ideas about what might be going on here and what could be done to remedy the problem?

### Update:

I was able to access this phone and when I pull the jpg files off of the sdcard, it says that the files are 3.5 - 4.0 MB in size, but they cannot be opened and may be corrupted... but the files on the other phones work normally.

Comment: How is the image being saved to disk?

Comment: added the "save to SD card" portion of my code to the original question.

Comment: But are the images saved in her SD card correct?

Comment: Right now she is saying that she can't see the photos in her gallery. Could be that her media hasn't refreshed or could be that the images were never saved...

Comment: I think the problem could be that I am explicitly using the "/sdcard/" directory. I will try using the system variable and will report back when I have the opportunity to test it.

Comment: Okay I have an update here - I was able to access this phone and when I pull the jpg files off of the sdcard, it says that the files are 3.5 - 4.0 MB in size, but they cannot be opened and may be corrupted... but the files on the other phones work normally.

Comment: tried that: `new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "imageFileName.jpg")`??

Comment: new File( "/sdcard/", currentFilename + ".jpg" ), instead of hardcoding the root folder can you please use getEnviorment().getExternelStorage() and try it

Comment: @Chris please add the updates to the post(question)...

Comment: What is `data` in `outStream.write(data);` and how do you get it?

Comment: @pawelzieba - I updated the original post, let me know if you need more info

I will award the bounty for this when I can, I have not been able to test on the problem device(s) at this point but have found other devices that are having the same issue.

Comment: @SudeepSR - I am now using `Environment.getExternalStorage()` and still having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like problem with picture sizes. Decoding data from array to picture when width and heigh are wrong results with scrambled image.

Pictures might be taken with supported screen sizes:

```
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

try to set one of them, for example the biggest, as picture size:

```
List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Size theBiggest=null;
int maxWidth = 0;
for (Size s : sizes) {
    if (s.width > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = s.width;
        theBiggest = s;
    }
}

params.setPictureSize(theBiggest.width, theBiggest.height);
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: This does work for retrieving the possible sizes and setting the photo size. I will report back when I have the opportunity to test on a device that I know is having problems.

Comment: Sorry you didn't get the full bounty, it isn't giving me a way to award it at this point.

Comment: This fixed an issue I found whilst working with some HTC devices - the default picture size was being set to 320 x 240

Answer (score 0):

Compress the bitmap in JPEG format into the output stream.. Assuming `data` is a `Bitmap`  type

```
currentFilename = String.format("%d", System.currentTimeMillis());              
outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + currentFilename + ".jpg");   
data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream );    
outStream.close();
```

You can change the compression ratio parameter to the `compress` api.. for example, pass 80 to get 80% compression.

[This post](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066) may have some relation to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Images need to be cached to sdcard in order to achieve full (non-compressed) size. Steps are easy

1. capture image
2. save captured image to sdcard
3. load saved image from sdcard
4. convert it to byte array and add as a ByteArrayBody, or as you o you might skip step 3 and create a file body with cached file.

Note: Currently i am away from my pc. I will post an detailed answer if there is no detailed post. Good luck.